# Issues with confusionMatrix in R: statistics part missing

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to evaluate performance results from a random forest machine learning algorithm but getting an error while trying to extract required parameters from caret package.

```
if(!require(caret)) install.packages('caret')
library(caret)

if(!require(class)) install.packages('class')
library(class)

if(!require(data.table)) install.packages('data.table')
library(data.table) # used for fread

if(!require(e1071)) install.packages('e1071')
library(e1071)

if(!require(ggplot2)) install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)

if(!require(knitr)) install.packages('knitr')
library(knitr)

if(!require(kableExtra)) install.packages('kableExtra')
install.packages("kableExtra")

if(!require(MLmetrics)) install.packages('MLmetrics')
library(ModelMetrics)

if(!require(randomForest)) install.packages('randomForest')
library(randomForest)

if(!require(reshape2)) install.packages('reshape2')
library(reshape2)

if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)

if(!require(tidyr)) install.packages('tidyr')
library(tidyr)

dataset_url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/332/online+news+popularity.zip"

# Download and extract the dataset
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "online_news_popularity.zip")

download.file(dataset_url, temp_file)
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)

# Load the dataset into a data.table
data <- fread(file.path(temp_dir, "OnlineNewsPopularity/OnlineNewsPopularity.csv"))

shares01 <- rep(0, length(data$shares))
# initializes a new variable shares01 that has same length as shares and initial value set to 0

shares01[data$shares > median(data$shares)] <- 1 # popular articles are defined as 1

set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")

#Removing non predictive variables
data <- subset( data, select = -c(url, timedelta,is_weekend) )

# Scaling by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard dev
data <- subset(data,select=-c(shares))

data <- data.frame(data,shares01)

# Identify the columns to be scaled (exclude "shares01" column)
cols_to_scale <- setdiff(names(data), "shares01")

# Scale the selected columns in the data frame
scaled_data <- data
scaled_data[cols_to_scale] <- lapply(data[cols_to_scale], scale)

#generating indexing for randomly splitting the main dataset into training and test sets
initial_index <- createDataPartition(y = scaled_data$shares01, times = 1, p = 0.98, list = FALSE)

train_set <- scaled_data[-initial_index,]

test_set <- scaled_data[initial_index,]

#generating indexing for randomly further splitting the train data into training and test sets

initial_index <- createDataPartition(y = train_set$shares01, times = 1, p = 0.9, list = FALSE)

train_train_set <- train_set[-initial_index,]

train_test_set <- train_set[initial_index,]

# Create the trainControl object for cross-validation settings
ctrl_rf <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
#cv method stands for k-cross fold validation which is 5 in this case.

# Train the Random Forest model using cross-validation
model_rf <- train(shares01 ~ ., data = train_train_set, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl_rf)

# Make predictions on the test set using the trained model
predictions_rf <- predict(model_rf, newdata = train_test_set)

# Actual values of the response variable in the test set
actual_values <- as.factor(train_test_set$shares01)

# Create the confusion matrix
conf_matrix_rf <- confusionMatrix(actual_values,predictions_rf)

# Extract metrics
accuracy_rf <- conf_matrix_rf$overall["Accuracy"]
```

Getting following error:

```
> accuracy_rf <- conf_matrix_rf$overall["Accuracy"]
Error in conf_matrix_rf$overall :
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I am getting incorrect values in my confusion matrix which are verified when I try to manually compute the confusion matrix using table function.

```
# Confusion matrix 
conf_matrix <- table(predictions_rf, actual_values) 
# Calculate True Positives (TP), True Negatives (TN), False Positives (FP), and False Negatives (FN) 
TP_rf <- conf_matrix[2, 2] 
TN_rf <- conf_matrix[1, 1] 
FP_rf <- conf_matrix[1, 2] 
FN_rf <- conf_matrix[2, 1] 

accuracy_rf <- (TP_rf + TN_rf) / (TP_rf + TN_rf + FP_rf + FN_rf)
precision_rf <- TP_rf / (TP_rf + FP_rf) recall_rf <- TP_rf / (TP_rf + FN_rf) 
f1_score_rf <- 2 * (precision_rf * recall_rf) / (precision_rf + recall_rf)
```

Comment: I think you need to specify that you're modelling a factor to begin with: 
`model_rf <- train(as.factor(shares01) ~ ., data = train_train_set, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl_rf)`
(or do it somewhere further upstream)

Also, your reprex could do with some library() calls to data.table and caret.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify that you're modelling a factor to begin with:

`model_rf <- train(as.factor(shares01) ~ ., data = train_train_set, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl_rf)`

(or do it somewhere further upstream)

Also, just as an aside, your reprex could do with some library() calls to data.table and caret.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming @gladys_c_hugh's answer is correct:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(data.table)
library(e1071)
library(randomForest)

dataset_url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/332/online+news+popularity.zip"

# Download and extract the dataset
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "online_news_popularity.zip")
download.file(dataset_url, temp_file)
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)
data <- fread(file.path(temp_dir, "OnlineNewsPopularity/OnlineNewsPopularity.csv"))

shares01 <- rep(0, length(data$shares))
shares01[data$shares > median(data$shares)] <- 1
set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")
#> Warning in set.seed(1, sample.kind = "Rounding"): non-uniform 'Rounding'
#> sampler used
data <- subset( data, select = -c(url, timedelta,is_weekend) )
data <- subset(data,select=-c(shares))
data <- data.frame(data,shares01)

cols_to_scale <- setdiff(names(data), "shares01")
scaled_data <- data
scaled_data[cols_to_scale] <- lapply(data[cols_to_scale], scale)

initial_index <- createDataPartition(y = scaled_data$shares01, times = 1, p = 0.98, list = FALSE)
train_set <- scaled_data[-initial_index,]
test_set <- scaled_data[initial_index,]
initial_index <- createDataPartition(y = train_set$shares01, times = 1, p = 0.9, list = FALSE)
train_train_set <- train_set[-initial_index,]
train_test_set <- train_set[initial_index,]

ctrl_rf <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
model_rf <- train(as.factor(shares01) ~ ., data = train_train_set, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl_rf)
predictions_rf <- predict(model_rf, newdata = train_test_set)
actual_values <- as.factor(train_test_set$shares01)

conf_matrix_rf <- confusionMatrix(actual_values,predictions_rf)
conf_matrix_rf$overall["Accuracy"]
#>  Accuracy 
#> 0.5890603
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I tried the code by @jared_mamrot but still got the following error:

    > conf_matrix_rf$overall["Accuracy"]
    Error in conf_matrix_rf$overall : 
    $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

    > conf_matrix_rf[,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0  375

Comment: Do you get the error if you run the commands in my answer in a new session @munibullah? Or when you run the commands with your actual data?